# New setup, muzzled audio, any help is appreciated

Tags: audio

I have a new setup that I'm pretty sure is not wired correctly. Yes the room is dusty as anything. The audio sounds very muzzled and there is not much bass. I'm guessing I'm missing a channel but I'm by no means an expert. I have the following equipment,

(1) DN-474A - 2x2-Channel Dual-Impedance Amplifier

(1) SiriusXM Grace Digital BR3 Streamer

(1) CESS-064-3f Speaker Cables to RCA Plugs Adapter, 2-Channel (3 FEET) - Streaming device to AMP.

(12) SoundTube 6.5" Coax Pendant 70v Black

(1) 18AWG Low Voltage LED Cable 2 Conductor Black Sleeve in-Wall Speaker Wire UL Listed Class 2 - From Amp to the speakers which are daisy chained.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you describe how you tested each component before connecting them all together this way?

Comment: @jay613 This setup wasn't tested, that would've been a great idea!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with DIY Home Improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two channels of audio in but one channel of speaker out seems - odd.

Particularly since the amp does not appear to have a function to combine stereo input to mono output - so there's that.

The wiring on the input also appears to be ignoring the fact that each channel has **+**, **G**round/earth, and **-**, and seems to have one channel connected to **1+** and **1G**, while the other is connected to **1-** and **2+** with **2G** and **2-** left unconnected, which is likely the core problem. **You're listening to the *difference* between the left and right channel's **+** signals.**

[image: From denon manual pdf]

[image: From question]

Presumably without a sheild wire, the inputs should be to **1+** & **1-** and the other channel to **2+** & **2-** with **1G** & **2G** either left unconnected or connected to a "ground" of the streaming box (which it seems to lack.) And if you want anything other than the one channel all your speakers are connected to, you need 2 different speaker cables each running to half your speakers.

Ah, this is hiding in there, and applies to you:

[image: From denon manual pdf]

So jumper wire from the **- input** (where the input from the streamer comes in on the black wire) to the **G input** on each channel.

Comment: Brilliant eye and answer.   OP [may or may not](https://crookwood.com/blog/dealing-with-unbalanced-gear-in-the-studio) want to jumper the **-** and **0** terminals.  Assuming the connected equipment is line-powered, the **-** inputs should be connected to household equipment ground at their end, but "should be" doesn't mean they are, and if not, they should be jumpered at this end, but  they should not be connected at both ends.

Comment: First I disconnected all the inputs then connected 1+ skipped g and connected 1-. I did the same with channel 2. The system instantly sounded great! I then jumpered 2- to 2g and 1g and I can't notice a difference. Either way the @Ecnerwal has the system working and sounding great. I'm happy to accept the answer, I'm just confused by the jumper situation now.

Comment: If you have no problems with hum, it may not matter. It was mentioned in the manual, and the input you have is unbalanced. I see the downvote fairy has come by...